# Here's another cryptogram! But don't look too far

Tags: cipher

Here is another cryptogram. Don't look too far.

2. `ndfd kx z ygn  fh;glbfz Q`

And also, the 2 is a hint.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solution:

> Here is a 6th cryptogram!

Reasoning:

> Go up one row of the keyboard. The c and m from "cryptogram" both come from the space bar in the original. Though some of the spaces in the original are actually spaces. I think the 2 is indicating that 2 of the spaces are actually letters, but it could be something else.

Comment: yeah, but the 2 actually means "down". If you have a keyboard that has a number pad at the side you'll see that the 2 stands for down. But anyway that's correct. That Qn just lasted 9 minutes. I'll accept the answer when i can.

Comment: It was a quick one, but a cute one. I see the 2 reasoning now - I do have a number pad, but don't use it for directional navigation or I would have seen it.

Comment: You could add ¨Enter¨ if you feel it does not make the solution to obvious, that way the lateral(or literal if you will) thinking works for everyone.